# Javascript regex breaking on selection of forward slash

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

Using regex to link `@something` and `#something` in a string. In both cases it's working fine. Trying to use same method to link `/something`, but it breaks everything.

Works for `@` and `#`
http://jsbin.com/todomuca/3/edit

Doesn't work for `/` due to link 44:
http://jsbin.com/todomuca/4/edit

Any idea why it's breaking?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
<head>
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<p linkify="twitter">some @username and #hashtag and now trying /test</p>

<!-- javascript -->
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>

angular.module('linkify', []);

angular.module('linkify')
  .filter('linkify', function () {
      'use strict';

      function linkify (_str, type) {
        if (!_str) {
          return;
        }

        var _text = _str.replace( /(?:https?\:\/\/|www\.)+(?![^\s]*?")([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])?/ig, function(url) { 
            var wrap = document.createElement('div');
            var anch = document.createElement('a');
            anch.href = url;
            anch.target = "_blank";
            anch.innerHTML = url;
            wrap.appendChild(anch);
            return wrap.innerHTML;
        });

        // bugfix
        if (!_text) {
          return '';
        }

        // Twitter
        if (type === 'twitter') {
          _text = _text.replace(/(|\s)*@(\w+)/g, '$1<a href="https://twitter.com/$2" target="_blank">@$2</a>');
          _text = _text.replace(/(^|\s)*#(\w+)/g, '$1<a href="https://twitter.com/search?q=%23$2" target="_blank">#$2</a>');
          _text = _text.replace(/(^|\s)*\/(\w+)/g, '$1<a href="https://twitter.com/search?q=$2" target="_blank">#$2</a>');
        }

        // Github
        if (type === 'github') {
          _text = _text.replace(/(|\s)*@(\w+)/g, '$1<a href="https://github.com/$2" target="_blank">@$2</a>');
        }

        return _text;
      }

      //
      return function (text, type) {
        return linkify(text, type);
      };
  })
  .factory('linkify', ['$filter', function ($filter) {
    'use strict';

    function _linkifyAsType (type) {
      return function (str) {(type, str);
        return $filter('linkify')(str, type);
      };
    }

    return {
      twitter: _linkifyAsType('twitter'),
      github: _linkifyAsType('github'),
      normal: _linkifyAsType()
    };
  }])
  .directive('linkify', ['$filter', '$timeout', 'linkify', function ($filter, $timeout, linkify) {
    'use strict';

    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        var type = attrs.linkify || 'normal';
        $timeout(function () { element.html(linkify[type](element.html())); });
      }
    };
  }]);


var app = angular.module("app", ['linkify']);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your question needs to contain all the code required to reproduce your problem. You can't use jsbin/jsfiddle/any other code hosting service to provide the *only* content in your question. You don't even include the regular expression in question.

Comment: @meagar, sorry forgot to include it. See edit. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re running replacements on raw HTML, which, after earlier replacements, include `</a>`, which matches your `/`-matching regular expression. You can try matching them all at the same time:

```
var TWITTER_LINK = /(?:^|\s)([@#/])(\w+)/g;

var html = text.replace(TWITTER_LINK, function (match, type, name) {
    var url = {
        '@': 'https://twitter.com/' + name,
        '#': 'https://twitter.com/search?q=%23' + name,
        '/': 'https://twitter.com/search?q=' + name
    }[type];

    return '<a href="' + url + '">' + match + '</a>';
});
```

That’s still not really pleasant, though; I would use the DOM.

```
var TWITTER_LINK = /(?:^|\s)([@#/])(\w+)/g;
var result = document.createDocumentFragment();
var lastIndex = 0;
var match;

while ((match = TWITTER_LINK.exec(text)) {
    result.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text.substring(lastIndex, match.index)));
    lastIndex = match.index;

    var type = match[1];
    var name = match[2];

    var url = {
        '@': 'https://twitter.com/' + encodeURIComponent(name),
        '#': 'https://twitter.com/search?q=%23' + encodeURIComponent(name),
        '/': 'https://twitter.com/search?q=' + encodeURIComponent(name)
    }[type];

    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = url;
    link.appendChild(document.createTextNode(match[0]));
    result.appendChild(link);
}

result.appendChild(document.createTextNode(text.substring(lastIndex)));
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, trying to integrate your solution into my code. Did you try it in jsbin?

Comment: Fully fleshed-out answer +1 :)